# Passing Variable from table into shell script

Tags: shell, while-loop

I have a table in below format.
[image]
Now, I am trying to get the values from table and pass it in shell script .

```
#!/bin/bash
# Connect to DB and spool query result into a CSV file
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/oracle/current
nohup $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s -s user/password@TEST123 << EOF
set echo off head off feed off pagesize 0 trimspool on linesize 1000 colsep   ,
spool output.csv
select Url , TAG from ABHAY_TEST;
spool off;
exit;
EOF
# Using while loop read values into variables from CSV file and create flat   file for each records
counter=1
while IFS=, read -r V1 V2
 do
  curl -s "${V1}" | grep -Po "${V2}" | wc -l
  counter=$(( counter + 1 ))
  done < output.csv
```

But I am unable to get the desired result. I am sure I am doing mistake while collecting the data from Table and passing it as variable in script.

Can someone help me with same ?

Comment: This seems to try and mix SQL and shell statements... the shell doesn't know what to do with your first line. Also, the assignment to `$count` won't work. Try https://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: It'll actually misunderstand `select` as a shell keyword if you use Bash.

Comment: Now, I am able to get the data . But I think I am doing wrong while passing it curl command

Comment: You've changed 100% of the code in your question.

Comment: @user2854333, Isn't curl producing what you expect. Run it without grep and check.

Comment: I think it is happening as the V1 and V2 are not taking correct values. I tried to print them and issue